# Quick and effective ways to learn and read scores(piano)

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, self-learning

I have no music background or whatsoever.

I am interested in self-learning piano, how do I learn to read music notes?

Answer (score 2):

*A good way to start is by going through a method book of some kind.*

Something like [Piano for dummies](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0470496444/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=0470496444&linkCode=as2&tag=sheepi-21), or something similar, where it's a start to finish style method book.  At some point in there you'll get a good grounding of who the staff works.  *The advantage of doing it this way is that for a while you have a consistent learning curve, taken at the pace of the book, giving you a stable place to learn from.*

From Here I'd get some of the finger exercise books, where the important part is less the sheet music, but more the shapes involved.  You're still using sheet music to get the basic idea, but then you can go off on your own fairly easily.  You don't need to hit the wall of understanding which note means which key for every note.

From there I would say just start reading sheet music.  if you don't understand a symbol, look it up, the resources for basic sheet music are everywhere on the internet, and free!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, get a teacher !! Books, internet etc. will give a grounding, but music is not a science. As an art, it has human intervention, so being able to ask questions that are answered by an expert - a teacher - who can shape the answers to your own understanding - is the best response to this. Imagine before you could read words, you tried to learn to do so without another human to help. Progress would have been rather slow !There's a lot more to just reading the dots than pressing the notes down, but if that's what someone wants to do, so be it.

Comment: getting a male , female piano teacher is better?

Comment: 'Getting a male, female piano teacher is better'- than what ? Yes, I'd go for one or the other !!